# How do I fetch JSON data from a web service? iOS Objective-c

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, sqlite

I can't find a helpful example right now. I have a php script on my server that returns all the data from a selected database tables. I am trying to fetch that from my client side ios device and parse that json so I can look through what is there and add some of that data to my sqlite database. I am using fmdb as a wrapper right now. Here is the code i have for connecting to the server and im not sure where to go from there

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://index.php"];

NSString * post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lang=%@",@"English"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

My json data looks like this

```
{"login":[{"userid":"1","password":"test","aclevel":"1"}],"answers":[{"aid":"1","qid":"1","sid":"1","freetext":null,"a":null,"b":null,"c":null,"d":null,"e":null,"f":null,"g":null,"h":null,"i":null,"j":null,"synch":null,"type":null},{"aid":"5","qid":"5","sid":"5","freetext":null,"a":null,"b":null,"c":null,"d":null,"e":null,"f":null,"g":null,"h":null,"i":null,"j":null,"synch":null,"type":null}],"projects":{"pid":"3","name":"apmatt","descr":"tapest","creator":"macurlatt","datetime":null,"synch":null},"questions":[{"qid":"1","pid":"1","sid":"1","question":null,"a":null,"b":null,"c":null,"d":null,"e":null,"f":null,"g":null,"h":null,"i":null,"j":null,"synch":null,"type":null}],"surveys":[{"sid":"2","pid":"2","name":"matt","descr":"test","creator":"matt","datetime":null,"synch":null},{"sid":"3","pid":"3","name":"amatt","descr":"taest","creator":"maatt","datetime":null,"synch":null}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if you are sure that server is returning so valid JSON. iOS provides `NSJSONSerialization` class to let you achieve this. The following lines of code give you the outlook on the process:

```
__block id data = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse*       response, NSData* responseData, NSError* err) {
    data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
}];
```

If response is in a valid JSON format you would get your data back in "`data`" variable that would either be a NSArray or a NSDictionary based on the format of the data, it has parsed.

Comment: I'm getting variable not assignable in the above code at the data line. any suggestions

Comment: @WilliamBrasky Didn't get you. What did you mean by variable? You can receive anything in `responseData` and the code should work till you are getting some valid JSON.

Comment: That is because you are assigning value to variable which was defined outside the block. Change first line to __block id data = nil;

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stupid error on my part. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I dont feel you are doing anything wrong by using POST and it is not anyhow related to server side db changes as well. Until your `myData` variable contains some junk you can POST safely. However, consider url encoding your `post` variable before you use it `NSString *post =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"any-data=%@",myData] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Ok so when i am stepping through it I can see that my 6 tables are being added to the data object and each one gets key/value pairs dependent on what was coming from the json. When I try to output it, it says null though, Is this expected?

Comment: Are you stepping through in server or client? I suppose you are in client and you are getting data back correctly from the server and those have been successfully parsed and added to a NSDictionary pointed by `data` variable. If this is so, you have some other issue with your output code and thats a different story, I guess.

Comment: However, If you feel that parsing does not work for server data, try logging that first. Use `NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` to generate string representation of server message and use `NSLog(@"%@",dataStr);` to see what is coming down. This might help you sort things out.